# Place 3 check marks in a list tableview, press button, display 3 columns in a new tableview

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios

I currently have a List TableView where I can place check marks on any of the Products in that list.  Right now, there is no outlet to handle the check marks.  What I'd like to do is once the user places check marks on Product names in that list, press a button which would pass those Products' details over to a new tableview, displaying the details of those Products in a side-by-side column-type of tableview for a side-by-side comparison of the 3 Products' details.  I could really use some help on the following and any help provided would be much appreciated.

1) Take the check marks and press a button to send that to a new view.  I have no idea how to associate and connect those check marks to a button and then program that button to send the details to a new tableview.

2) Create a new view with a tableview capable of displaying 3 side-by-side columns in a tableview.  I have read some about creating tables that appear to have multiple columns, but I'm not exactly sure how this is achieved.

Any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about number 2, but here's how I'd handle number 1:

Store the "check mark" as an attribute of each Product object in the array where your first table view is getting its data. Then, when you push the next view controller, populate an array by checking which products have a check mark attribute and adding them to a new array for your second table view's data source.

Comment: Thanks Luke.  Much appreciated.  I have a few questions on what you suggested.  I'm new at this so some of my questions might be pretty basic. This is a Core Data app, just keeping that in mind, if I use an array like you mentioned, will that be temporarily storing the "check mark"?  I would want it to be a temporary store and not actually store that check mark as a permanent attribute.  I was reading something about NSUserDefaults and how that could be used to temporarily store check mark attributes and thought maybe that could be utilized to temp hold the check marks and pass to the new view

Comment: I wouldn't use NSUserDefaults - that's meant for storing information outside of your app. If you don't want check marks associated with the product objects themselves, you could have a separate array containing a boolean value at each index specifying whether the product at that index has a check mark.

Comment: Thanks for sharing that info about NSUSerDefaults.  I wasn't quite sure how that worked.  It sounds like, as you mentioned, temporarily storing the check mark as an attribute to where it acts much the way an on/off toggle switch does, would be my best option.  Thanks for your help, much appreciated.